# Can GDAL Retile run multi-threaded?

Tags: geoserver, gdal

gdal_retile is currently using only one CPU of the available eight and it is taking a while (48 hours already) to retile 5TB of data.

Comment: I had the same issue, but with ``gdal2tiles``. See [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/performance-of-google-map-tile-creation-processes/74446#74446), it may help shed some light.