# What is the fastest version of gdal2tiles?

Tags: python, gdal, tiles, gdal2tiles, cesium

I have multi-CPU linux server, so I wonder what is the fastest parallel version of `gdal2tiles.py` ?

My Ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
```

How I install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
```

Package version:

```
apt-show-versions python-gdal
python-gdal/precise uptodate 1.10.0-1~precise2
```

And under `/usr/bin/` I have `gdal2tiles.py`.

Does it make sense is to update `python-gdal` package > 1.10.0(maybe build newer version from source), where I can see changelog about `gdal2tiles.py`?

After some googling I found that there are some patched versions of original `gdal2tiles.py` and some parallel versions of `gdal2tiles.py`. So I wonder why this functionality is not included in official package?

If anyone point to stable and fast version of `gdal2tiles.py` I can run some benchmarks for community.

Here is my script that I use for benchmark using original single threaded `gdal2tiles.py`.

```
set -x # Dump each line of this script
set -e # Stop on first error

DATASET="my_dataset"
LEVELS_OF_DETAIL=19

time gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "0,0,0" orthomaps/$DATASET/global.vrt orthomaps/$DATASET/orthophoto_*.tif

#Default gdal2tiles.py
GDAL_TO_TILES="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py"
time $GDAL_TO_TILES -z 0-$LEVELS_OF_DETAIL orthomaps/$DATASET/global.vrt default_gdal2tiles_$DATASET
```

What versions I have tried:

1. Original version of `gdal2tiles.py` (single threaded).
2. Patch from [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4379) to make original `gdal2tiles.py` parallel, produce missing tiles.
3. Version from [here](https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp) (also parallel), [produce missing tiles](https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp/issues/4).
4. Version from [here](https://github.com/GitHubRGI/geopackage-python/blob/master/Tiling/gdal2tiles_parallel.py) (also parallel), I [can't even run it](https://github.com/GitHubRGI/geopackage-python/issues/33).
5. Maptiler, works well, but cost money.
6. [tiler-tools](https://github.com/vadp/tilers-tools) cause an [error](https://github.com/vadp/tilers-tools/issues/1).

If creating a TMS tiles with parallel `gdal2tiles`is an issue, I can move to any other tile format which is supported in Cesium( by cesium tile provider) and have parallel tiler, any ideas?

Related questions:

[Performance of google map tile creation processes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/performance-of-google-map-tile-creation-processes)

[How to cut a 'tiled image' from a raster dataset using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5101/how-to-cut-a-tiled-image-from-a-raster-dataset-using-gdal)

Comment: If using a GUI tool would be ok, you can try Maptiler (by the gdal2tiles.py developer, sadly not open source nor fully free) or Tilemill. I think, but I might be wrong, that the free QGIS plugin QTIles uses parallel processing as well.

Comment: Since you alluded to them:  See this project for speed improvements, https://github.com/pramsey/gdal2tilesp/  features "Parallel processing, to use all available machine cores when generating tiles."  This helped me immensely.  My forked enhancements for WEBP here https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp/

Comment: @RobLabs I have tried your version here is bugreport https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp/issues/4 , what version of gdal2tiles.py you was using originally?

Comment: I'm also interested in creating tiles in parallel. Tried gdal2tiles_parallel.py but that creates several empty tiles. For instance, my map cover a part of Brazil but the created tile cover the entire world and is full of blank PNGs. Is there away to skip tiles not covered by the original map?

Comment: I was unsuccessfully attempting to install gdal2tiles and your step by step to install the vanilla version solved my problem.  UPVOTED  :)